# Break array of int to stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class

```
public class Targets {
    public int[] miniTargets;

    public Targets(int t) {
        miniTargets = new int[t];
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            miniTargets[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to count how many `miniTargets` I have in `Targets` collection
but I am stuck with the `flatMap`:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Targets> lst = new ArrayList<Targets>();
        lst.add(new Targets(5));
        lst.add(new Targets(15));
        lst.add(new Targets(25));

        int cnt = (int)lst.stream().map(tg -> tg.miniTargets).flatMap(...).count()
        System.out.println(cnt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the total of the lengths of the `miniTargets` arrays :

```
int cnt = lst.stream()
             .mapToInt(tg -> tg.miniTargets.length)
             .sum();
```

If you want an IntStream containing the miniTargets :

```
IntStream minis = lst.stream()
                     .flatMapToInt (tg -> IntStream.of(tg.miniTargets));
```

Comment: You don't want count(), you want sum(). See my answer

Comment: and if i want to convert it to stream of int - how can i achieve it?

Comment: @li-raz What should that stream of int contain? All the elements of the miniTargets arrays?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `flatMap`. Just call `mapToInt` with the length of each array and then call `sum()`.

```
int cnt = lst.stream().mapToInt(tg -> tg.miniTargets.length).sum();
```

Though you may want to use an accessor and encapsulate your datas:

```
class Targets {
   private miniTargets;
   ...
   public int size() {
       return miniTargets.length;
   }
}
```

and then it'll come:

```
int cnt = lst.stream().mapToInt(Targets::size).sum();
```

If you want an IntStream will all the values, you can do:

```
IntStream allValues = lst.stream()
                         .map(tg -> tg.miniTargets)
                         .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream);
```